# ASP.NET Core 2 MVC - code execution after returning the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

the idea in my code is to return the view from HTTP request to the client and keep executing the code (for some 10-20 seconds), thus allowing the page returned to the client to inquire of the status of the job execution by AJAX. So, it's a kind of "background" task, but very short, and with the only goal to keep the user interface responsive and display messages as the job progresses. I've read a ton of articles on the subject, and here is what I have now (the code is abbreviated to only the important parts):

```
public MyController(ApplicationDbContext _db)
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext _db)
    {
        db = _db;
    }

    public IActionResult Test1()
    {
        Exec(); // compile warning CS4014, since the call is not await-ed
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Test2()
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { Exec(); });
        return View();
    }

    public async Task Exec()
    {
        try
        {
            await db.Employee.ToListAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

In the action Test1 I use a non-awaited async call, and it allows the execution to continue while the called function is being executed - no obvious errors here.

The action Test2 doesn't work because ApplicationDbContext in the Exec method will already be disposed of, and an exception will occur.

I wonder which is the correct way to acomplish this task and if it's possible to have ApplicationDbContext still avaiable when using the second option.

Also, even if the first option works, I'd like to have some explanation why does it work (I know it sounds a little funny, but I'd like to know that the principle applied will be working under any condition, not just in this one particular case).

**ADDED**: now I found that in reality neither does Test1 really work, it seems that there's no error only because Exec is here faster than the whole HTTP request, ie. ApplicationDbContext was still not dispsed of!

Comment: Why don't you want make `Test1` async and await `Exec`?

Comment: Because the whole idea is NOT to await for Exec!

Comment: What do you mean by not awaiting it?

Comment: It means I want Test1 action to continue executing ini parallel with Exec and return the view as soon as possible. Exec needs 10-20 seconds to execute.